# Cannot Access LinkedHashMap in inner class

Tags: java, android

I have the following code:

```
final LinkedHashMap<String, Line> trainLinesMap = MetraRail.myDbHelper.getTrainLinesHashMap();

// Create an array of proper line names for the listview adapter.
String[] train_lines_long_names = new String[trainLinesMap.size()];

Iterator<Entry<String, Line>> it = trainLinesMap.entrySet().iterator();
for (int i = 0; it.hasNext(); i++) {
    Map.Entry<String, Line> pairs = (Map.Entry<String, Line>) it.next();
    train_lines_long_names[i] = (String) pairs.getKey();
}

// Override the default list adapter so we can do 2 things: 1) set custom background colors
// on each item, and 2) so we can more easily add onclick handlers to each item.
listview.setAdapter(
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.select_line_row_layout,
        R.id.select_line_line_label, train_lines_long_names) {

                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                    // Change the background color of each item in the list.
                    final String line_label_long = textView.getText().toString();
                    final int line_color = trainLinesMap.get(line_label_long).getColorInt();
                    textView.setBackgroundColor(line_color);

                    // Add onclick handlers to each item.
                    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent i = new Intent();
                            i.setClassName("garrettp.metrarail", 
                                    "garrettp.metrarail.screens.SelectStations");
                            i.putExtra("garrettp.metrarail.line.short", 
                                    trainLinesMap.get(line_label_long).getShortName());
                            i.putExtra("garrettp.metrarail.line.long", line_label_long);
                            i.putExtra("garrettp.metrarail.line.color", line_color);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    });

                    return textView;
                }
            });
```

At the line:

```
final int line_color = trainLinesMap.get(line_label_long).getColorInt();
```

I get a NullPointerException:

```
10-26 16:10:35.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1785): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-26 16:10:35.922: E/AndroidRuntime(1785):     at garrettp.metrarail.screens.SelectLine$1.getView(SelectLine.java:74)
```

Why is this? In a debugger, I've verified that trainLinesMap is correctly initialized and filled with values. It is successfully iterated over in the first for loop, so I know there are values there. But, when accessing the LinkedHashMap from my anonymous inner class, it is always null.

I was able to access a String array from this inner class, why can't I access a LinkedHashMap?

Comment: you can, the NPE is most likely from your map, right before that line add

    "System.err.println(line_label_long + " : " + trainLinesMap.get(line_label_long));"

it will probably be null

Comment: See my answer below, I solved this by assigning the result of trainLinesMap.get(line_label_long) to a temporary variable, and called .getColorInt() from the temporary variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by breaking up the line:

```
final int line_color = trainLinesMap.get(line_label_long).getColorInt();
```

into:

```
Line thisLine = trainLinesMap.get(line_label_long);
final int line_color = thisLine.getColorInt();
```

I'm not sure why this worked, but I no longer get NullPointerExceptions.